# Difference between MouseListener and MouseAdapter in Java

Tags: java, mouselistener

I can't seem to understand **the difference** between the 2 interfaces. Why can't MouseAdapter be implemented like MouseListener and can only be extended? I'm fairly new to Java.

Considering we want to perform an action that can be completed with **either** of these 2 interfaces.

Also, when would it be wise to use the one and when the other ?

Comment: Simple google foo would have told you the answer. My google foo shows [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/listeners-vs-adapters)

Comment: So, a mouse listener is an interface. That means it has no content. A interface is a basic structure. It does only contain method names. So, java sees, you implement MouseListener, what means, you have to have its methods, like released, so that they  can be called by AWT/swing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I can't seem to understand the difference between the 2 interfaces. Why can't MouseAdapter be implemented like MouseListener and can only be extended

[MouseAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) implements [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html).

**MouseAdapter**:

> An abstract adapter class for receiving mouse events. The methods in this class are empty. This class exists as convenience for creating listener objects.
>   Extend this class to create a MouseEvent (including drag and motion events) or/and MouseWheelEvent listener and override the methods for the events of interest

In absence of `MouseAdapter`, if you implement `MouseListener`, you have to provide implementation to all of these interface methods.

```
mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)
```

> when would it be wise to use the one and when the other ?

If you want to implement above 8 methods, implement `MouseListener`. If you want to provide implementation for only some of these 8 methods, use `MouseAdapter` and override only those methods of interest for you.

e.g. If you are interested only in implementing one event ( or few events) like  `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` event, best to use `MouseAdapter`. If you implement `MouseListener` interface in this case, you have to provide blank implementation for other methods, which you are not going to implement.

Comment: Thank you. I seem to understand how this interface works now :)
Thank you for the thorough explanation !

Answer (score 4):

MouseListener is preferred only when you override all abstract methods else MouseAdapter is the preferred choice.

Answer (score 2):

MouseListener is an Interface and MouseAdapter is an implementation of that. You can use the MouseAdapter in every place that you use a MouseListener.

But implementations have details that have be take in count.

Read the javadocs before decide.

[MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)
[MouseAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html)

Comment: So that would mean that Mouse Adapter is not an interface, but a method?

Answer (score 1):

MouseAdapter implements MouseListener already. The advantage to using MouseAdapter is so you don't have to define everything MouseListener forces you to. It's just an ease of use thing.

*If you don't need to define every method from MouseListener then it's perfectly fine to use MouseAdapter.*

MouseAdapter just contains the empty definitions for you to Override.